# TSQL to generate the dynamic SQL statement before execution

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a list of column names `a,b,c` is it possible to generate a `SQL` statement as `string` (to be executed inside `EXEC` as a dynamic SQL) based on the number of items in that column names.

So, if I have a table called `@src`

```
DECLARE @src AS TABLE
  (
     list VARCHAR(max)
  )

INSERT INTO @src
SELECT 'a'
UNION
SELECT 'b'
UNION
SELECT 'c'

SELECT *
FROM   @src
```

how can I generate a string dynamically `for each element in @src` to give a string `a,b,c`
which will be further utilized inside a `EXEC` statement like `EXEC('select'+a,b,c(coming from dynamic string)+'from mainTbl`

To better demonstrate this with a javascript string generator

```
var src = ['a','b','c'];
var target =['e','f','g'];
var beginning ='select';
var end = 'from mainTbl';
var newArray=[];
src.forEach((x,i,r)=>{newArray.push(x+' '+'as '+target[i]);});
var dynamicStr = beginning+' '+newArray.reduce(function(prev,current){return prev+', '+current;})+' '+end; //to be utilized inside SQL EXEC
```

[image: S1]

This is in javascript but is it possible for TSQL to generate this string for each element of `@src` so that whenever I edit `@src` the final result dynamically changes.

Comment: what is the wanted result?

Comment: The wanted result is to pass on a dynamic string inside `EXEC('select'+dynamicStr+' from mainTbl')` so that I can influence the outcome of the above statement only by making changes in `@src` (i.e. `UNION` more or delete some existing)

Comment: What part are you struggling with? Creating the dynamic statement? Executing the dynamic statement? Passing the table type parameter? Something else?

Comment: Yes, I am struggling with how to generate a string in SQL that would result in `dynamicStr=a,b,c` to be utilized as `EXEC('select'+dynamicStr+' from main')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly it looks like you just need to aggregate your "columns".

In SQLServer 2017+ you can use *string_agg()*

```
SELECT Concat('select ', String_Agg(quotename(list),', '), ' from t')
FROM   @src
```

Prior to 2017 you can use the clunkier *for xml path* syntax

```
select Concat('select ', 
    Stuff((
    select ', ' + QuoteName(list) 
    from @src
    for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, len(', '), ''),
    ' from t'
) as statement
```

Comment: Thanks. The server I am using is not 2017+. It is 2016. I can't test out the above. Sorry.

Comment: Then use the *old* `FOR XML PATH` method, @smpa01 . Unless advised otherwise, users here will assume you are using a fully supported version of the software (or perhaps even the latest), and 2016 entered extended support last year.

Comment: @smpa01 Ok I tend to avoid it if possible but have added a 2016 version above, see if that works for you?